Why ws.close() takes 30sec while all other are instantaneous
I'm developing a webapp in React with a backend in NodeJS on an Apache server. One feature of this webapp is a chat app using websocket (I'm not using socket.io for it). Everything worked fine on my local machine : I used wampserver to set up a local server and did everything in ws and http.
Now that I moved everything on my server, 99% of the websocket communications works fine. The 1% comes when I try to close the websocket on React. On my local machine ws.close() was instantaneous. On my server it takes 30sec.
I've been trying to find out where the issue comes from. I've looked at :

the apache server, but didn't understand how it would be that as all message go through it without problem except for that ws.close().

replacing ws.terminate() instead of ws.close(), but when a user refreshes his webpage, a ws.close() is still sent.

try to send a specific message to the server to initiate the close / terminate, but the still couldn't bypass the case where the user refreshes his page.


Here's a snippet of a code that creates the websocket on the frontend :

useEffect(() => {
        const establishConnection = async () => {
            if (user?.id !== undefined && grade !== undefined) {
                await establishNewSocket();
            }
        };
        establishConnection();
    }, [user, grade]);
    
async function establishNewSocket() {
        //if (socket && socket?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        //    socket.close(1000);
        //}

        const newSocket = new WebSocket(`xxxxxx/chat`);
        setSocket(newSocket);

        newSocket.addEventListener('open', async () => {
            try {
                    newSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'authenticate', token }));
                    newSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'firstConnection' }));
            } catch (error) {
                if (socket && socket?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    socket.close(3000);
                }
            }
            connection_resolvers.forEach(r => r.resolve());
        });

        // Gestion des erreurs WebSocket
        newSocket.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Error WebSocket', error);
        });

        // Gestion de la fermeture du WebSocket
        newSocket.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
        });
    }


Here's another snippet of a code that triggers the closing of the websocket :
const handleLogout = async () => {
  try {
    if (socket && socket?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
       socket.close(1000);
     }
     navigate('/login');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Logout error:', error);
  }
};

And here's the backend code :

index.js

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cron = require('node-cron');

const app = express();
const port = 8001;

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
  methods: ['PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'GET'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true  // Permet l'envoi des cookies
}));

const server = http.createServer(app);
const webSocketController = require('./controllers/webSocketController');
webSocketController(server);



a snippet of webSocketController.js

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const roomsAndUsers = {};

module.exports = (server) => {
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server, path: '/chat' });

    wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {

        ws.on('message', (messageAsString) => {
            const message = JSON.parse(messageAsString);

            if (message.type === 'authenticate') {
                handleAuthentication(ws, message.token);  // Authentication avec le token JWT
            } else if (ws.user) {
                ...
            } else {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'authError' }));
                ws.close(); 
            }
        });

        ws.on('close', () => {
            if (ws.user) {
                handleDisconnect(ws, `${room}`);
            }
        });
    });

    console.log("WebSocket server is running on the server");

function handleDisconnect(ws, room_variable_name) {
    ws.close();
    ....
};

And in case that would be useful, here's a snippet of the ssl.conf file :
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   DocumentRoot xxx
   ServerName xxx
   SSLEngine ON
   SSLCertificateFile xxx
   SSLCertificateKeyFile xxx
   SSLCertificateChainFile xxx

    ProxyPass "/api" "http://localhost:8001/api"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://localhost:8001/api"

    ProxyPass "/chat" "ws://localhost:8001/chat"
    ProxyPassReverse "/chat" "ws://localhost:8001/chat"

</VirtualHost>

I hope someone can help me on this.
Thanking you all in advance.

Could you try adding a console.log at the beginning of the 'close' event handler ? I suspect the event might be called more than once, slowing down everything.

Thanks for your answer Jean-Samuel. Which of the close event handler ? Frontend or backend ?

Backend add it before the if checking for ws.user
